# Why won't my submit button position properly?

Tags: css

This is a really simple CSS question, I think.

I'm playing with Magento and learning CSS (bad combination?). I'm trying to make a 2 line login box. The email and password field labels above their respective fields, and the submit button to the right of the input fields.

Alas no matter what I try the submit button ends up elsewhere (mostly on the first line). I've been at this for four hours, I've read more code from other websites and still can't get it to work!

```
.block-login {
float:right;
width:530px;
}

.block-login.block-content {
}

.mini-login-input {
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
height:100%
}

.mini-login-input.label {
}

.block-login.button {
}
```

The HTML it comes from (not written by me, Magento code):

```
<div class="block-login">

<form action="http://magento.local/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="mini-login-input">
            <label for="mini-login">Email:</label><br /><input type="text" name="login[username]" id="mini-login" class="input-text" />
        </div>
        <div class="mini-login-input">
            <label for="mini-password">Password:</label><br /><input type="password" name="login[password]" id="mini-password" class="input-text" />
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use a simple `<br/>` above the button.

Comment: When you ask client-side questions, like CSS, it isn't helpful to post your php mixed in with your html. Post what you see in your browser.

Comment: @mrtsherman cheers fixed that up now.

Comment: @Arif is right - http://jsfiddle.net/KMksm/4/

Comment: @Arif thanks so simple but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a table?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Email box here</td>
       <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Login button here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Password box here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not really tabular data. I think table styling is a good idea though. He can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

Comment: "What's wrong with a table?" There's no tabular data, that's what's wrong with using a table here.

Answer (score 0):

here you go dude, this should do it. just added a negative left margin and a top margin on your button http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/dXYE5/

as for magento and css being a bad combination, not at all. they go hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:

```
.block-login {
    float:right;
    width:530px;
}

.block-login.block-content {
    width:80%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.mini-login-input {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:100%
}

.mini-login-input>label {display:block}

.actions {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
}

.button {vertical-align:middle}

<div class="block-login">

<form action="http://magento.local/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="mini-login-input">
            <label for="mini-login">Email:</label><input type="text" name="login[username]" id="mini-login" class="input-text" />
        </div>
        <div class="mini-login-input">
            <label for="mini-password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="login[password]" id="mini-password" class="input-text" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Plays with width of blocks you can customize your form.